# ajax reloading the login model in case of error function which is not what i want

Tags: java, ajax, spring

login modal should not refresh in case of error in credentials through ajax, the need is to show error message on login modal if user enters wrong username or password, but every time it reloads the page and login modal disappears...

**This is my jsp**

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/custom/login/login-model.js" />"      type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <div class="modal-title center-align ">
                <h4>Sign In</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
                <form method="post" class="form-signin-signup" id="signinsubmit" action="${loginUrl}">
                        <div id="asas"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7" id="loginErrorMsg">
                                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                                    <div class="error">${error}</div>
                                </c:if>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="label.email"/></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control validate[required,custom[email]]" id="email" name="email"    placeholder="Username" style="width: 100%;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="label.password"/></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control validate[required]" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 100%;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7 remember-me" style="height: 36px;">
                                <input type="submit" id="submitButtonId" value="Signin" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block inline-block">
                                <div id="checking" class=" rowinline-block"></div>
                                <span class="errormess .pull-right alert"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7" style="text-align: center;">
                                <a href="#"><spring:message code="label.forgot.password"/></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                            <!-- the ajax result wrapper -->
                </form>
            <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" style="text-align: center;">
                        <spring:message code="label.dont.have.account"/><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" style="text-align: center;">
                        <a href="sign-up" class="btn btn-large btn-success bottom-space"><spring:message code="label.signUp"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div> -->
    </div>
```

**This is my ajax...**

```
$(document).on("submit", "#signinsubmit", function(e) {

var frm = $('#signinsubmit');
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

    type : frm.attr('method'),
    url : frm.attr('action'),
    data : frm.serialize(),
    success : function(res) {
            location.href = location.href;
            console.log(res);
    },
    error : function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            $('#loginErrorMsg').html(e);
            $("#asas").html(e);

            return false;
    }
});

});
```

**This is my controller...**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/access-denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView accessDeniedPage(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error) {
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
    m.addObject("user", getUserName());
    if (error != null) {
        m.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }
    m.setViewName("components/login-modal");
    return m;
}
```

**This is Spring security...**

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/my**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/data**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="email"
        password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/access-denied?error" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />

    <csrf disabled="true" /> <!-- TODO: CSRF should not be disabled -->
</http>
```

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: what do you mean whats wrong with this question?